# Strange output in printing a grep -c return

Tags: perl, grep

Below is a shell program, it's just me testing how to tell if the same Perl script is already running using the same parameters.

It works, but what strikes me as odd is the trailing zero after the count of lines.  I don't see where in my code that zero would be printed.  If I run that grep command from the command line it just returns the count, no trailing '0', but it doesn't work that way in the code.

Any clues anyone?

Thanks

**The App**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI;
$|=1;

my $q = CGI->new();
my $userid = $q->param("u");
my $check = "'perly.pl u=" . $userid . "'";

my $return= system("ps aux | grep $check | grep -v 'grep' -c");

print $return;
print "\n";

while(1)
{
        print "$userid...";
        sleep(3);
}

exit 0;
```

**The output**

> 2 0
>   PlasticProgrammer..PlasticProgrammer..PlasticProgrammer..PlasticProgrammer..PlasticProgrammer..PlasticProgrammer..PlasticProgrammer..PlasticProgrammer..PlasticProgrammer..PlasticProgrammer..PlasticProgrammer..

Comment: What does that pipeline you run with `system()` print out? I bet it's `2`.

Comment: And since you mention not understanding a "trailing zero", I suspect you don't understand how `system()` works or what it returns. Refresh yourself by [reading the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html), in particular the third paragraph.

Comment: @Shawn Yes I see now.  I'm "seeing" the grep value, and printing the "return".  Then my question would be is how do I capture the grep value within the Perl script?

Comment: Am guessing I have to use ps or EXEC to a file.  Will have to try it later and post result when I return.

Comment: DANGER!!!! `foo.cgi?u=%27%20%3B%20rm%20-rf%20%2F%20%3B%20%27` would cause `rm -rf /` to be executed!!! Please use `use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote ); my $grep_cmd = shell_quote('grep', '--', "perly.pl u=$userid"); system("... | $grep_cmd | ...")`

Comment: Even better, use [pgrep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) so you don't need to pass anything to the shell: `my $check = "perly.pl u=$userid"; system('pgrep', '-fc', $check);`

Answer (score 1):

You can easily capture the output and exit value of a command using [Capture::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny). Also, when using the built-in [system](https://perldoc.pl/functions/system), always make sure to check that the execution succeeded, if it failed this is indicated by a return value of -1.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Capture::Tiny 'capture_stdout';

my $check = "perly.pl u=foo";
my ($stdout, $exit) = capture_stdout { system 'pgrep', '-fc', $check };
die "pgrep failed: $!" if $exit == -1;
```

Remember that your output will most likely end in a newline, even just a count, so you probably want to [chomp](https://perldoc.pl/functions/chomp) it.

You can also use the [backticks/qx operator](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#qx/STRING/) to return just the STDOUT, but this will always pass the command through the shell, requiring you to use String::ShellQuote on your argument containing user input as noted by @ikegami.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use String::ShellQuote;

my $check = shell_quote "perly.pl u=foo";
my $stdout = `pgrep -fc $check`;
die "pgrep failed: $!" if $? == -1;
```

An alternative is [IPC::System::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::System::Simple), which provides `capturex`, a form of the backticks operator that takes a list of arguments like system and never passes them through the shell. By default it will throw an exception if the command fails or if there's a nonzero exit code, but you can specify to allow certain exit codes. Since pgrep returns a nonzero exit code if there's no matches, you want to allow nonzero exit codes.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::System::Simple qw(capturex EXIT_ANY $EXITVAL);

my $check = "perly.pl u=foo";
my $stdout = capturex EXIT_ANY, 'pgrep', '-fc', $check;
my $exit = $EXITVAL;
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is looking for a solution to this, good ideas up top but in the end I chose to create a unique temp file and pipe the output to that file.

Many ways, I found this the one that felt right for me.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI;
use File::Temp;
$|=1;

my $q = CGI->new();
my $userid = $q->param("u");
my $check = "'perly.pl u=" . $userid . "'";

my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime(time); 
$year += 1900;
$mon++;

my $uFile = $userid . $year . $mon . $mday . $hour . $min . $sec . ".dat";

my $command = "ps aux | grep $check | grep -v 'grep' -c > $uFile";

system($command);

if (open(my $fh, "$uFile"))
{
    while (my $line = <$fh>)
    {
        if($line>1)
        {
            print"\nApp is already running";
         }
    }

    close($fh);
    unlink($uFile);
}
exit 0;
```

Comment: This is still vulnerable to allow anyone to run whatever they want on your machine as @ikegami said. Don't do this. Either use String::ShellQuote on the args you pass through the shell, or use the options I mentioned that don't require going through the shell.